# HTML 5 code to add progress or load bar in android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am using HTML 5 to build mobile app and use Phonegap build to convert into .apk file.My app
have button which redirect user to web page and in-built android browser come into play to display webpage.Problem is webpage not shown until it fully loaded in browser.for fast internet connection it look smooth but for slow internet connection it looks app is hang for while.My question is how i add loading bar or screen in app so loading bar is appear and web page loading take place at its back

Comment: Are using InAppBrowser plugin of phonegap ?

Comment: not surely know.but phonegap plugin directory have childBrowser plugin

Comment: Are you using window.open() method to open the webpage ? It will be nice if you can provide some code snippets that depicts the story ...